# What is the function of peek command in OMNet++

Tags: omnet++, inet

In INET developer's guide, I found the following `peek`` commands. Can anyone please help me explaininge the differences between peek, peekAt, peekData, peekAllAsBytes, and peekAtFront?

Example command:

peek

```
auto firstHalf = udpHeader->peek(B(0), B(4));
```

peekData

```
auto data = packet->peekData();
```

peekAllAsBytes

```
auto data = packet->peekAllAsBytes();
```

peekAt

```
vector<Packet *> *Mac::fragment(Packet *packet, vector<b>& sizes)
{
auto offset = b(0); // start from the packet's beginning
auto fragments = new vector<Packet *>(); // result collection
for (auto size : sizes) { // for each received size do
auto fragment = new Packet("Fragment"); // header + data part +
˓→trailer
auto header = makeShared<MacHeader>(); // create new header
header->setFragmentOffset(offset); // set fragment offset for
˓→reassembly
fragment->insertAtFront(header); // insert header into fragment
**auto data = packet->peekAt(offset, size);**
}
```

peekAtFront

```
const auto& hdr = packet->peekAtFront<MacHeaderBase>();
```

For peekAtFront, I know it returns the header part of a packet. However, i don't understand what is the function of "MacHeaderBase".

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some explanation of these methods in `src/inet/common/packet/Packet.h` and `src/inet/common/packet/chunk/Chunk.h`:

1. **`peek()`**

> ```
> /**
>  * Returns the designated part of the data represented by this chunk in the
>  * requested representation. If the length is unspecified, then the length of
>  * the result is chosen according to the internal representation. The result
>  * is mutable iff the designated part is directly represented in this chunk
>  * by a mutable chunk, otherwise the result is immutable.
>  */
> template <typename T>
> const Ptr<T> peek(const Iterator& iterator, b length = b(-1), int flags = 0) const
> ```

2. **`peekData()`**

> ```
>  /**
>   * Returns the whole data part (excluding front and back popped parts) in the
>   * current representation. The length of the returned chunk is the same as
>   * the value returned by getDataLength(). The flags parameter is a combination
>   * of Chunk::PeekFlag enumeration members.
>   */
>  const Ptr<const Chunk> peekData(int flags = 0) const
> ```

3. **`peekAllAsBytes()`**

> ```
> /**
>  * Returns the whole packet (including front and back popped parts) as a
>  * sequence of bytes. The length of the returned chunk is the same as the
>  * value returned by getTotalLength(). The flags parameter is a combination
>  * of Chunk::PeekFlag enumeration members.
>  */
> const Ptr<const BytesChunk> peekAllAsBytes(int flags = 0) const
> ```

4. **`peekAt()`**

> ```
> /**
> * Returns the designated part of the packet as an immutable chunk in its
> * current representation. If the length is unspecified, then the length of
> * the result is chosen according to the current representation. The flags
> * parameter is a combination of Chunk::PeekFlag enumeration members.
> */
> const Ptr<const Chunk> peekAt(b offset, b length = b(-1), int flags = 0) const;
> ```

5. **`peekAtFront()`**

> ```
> /**
>  * Returns the designated part as an immutable chunk in its current
>  * representation. If the length is unspecified, then the length of the
>  * result is chosen according to the current representation. The flags
>  * parameter is a combination of Chunk::PeekFlag enumeration members.
>  */
>  const Ptr<const Chunk> peekAtFront(b length = b(-1), int flags = 0) const;
> ```

`MacHeaderBase` is class defined in `src/inet/linklayer/base/MacHeaderBase.msg`.

Comment: So, the basic difference between ```peek``` and ```peekAt``` is one returns mutable chunk and another immutable chunk?

Comment: Would you say what the function of ```const auto& hdr = packet->peekAtFront<MacHeaderBase>();```? Thank you

Comment: 1) Not exactly. `peek` returns a chunk pointed by current value of iterator (offset), while `peekAt` enables select the position (i.e. offset) we want to read.  2) `packet->peekAtFront<MacHeaderBase>` takes the first chunk from `packet` and tries convert it to `MacHeaderBase`. It throws an error when it canno cast the chunk to this type.